# Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED' - Pancakeswap

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap, pancakeswap

I am trying to swap a token on pancakeswap using node and ethers js. However getting into this error, "TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED" . The router has been given the approval/allowance to swap the tokens, I can see the approval is getting triggered correctly. However the swapping gets into error

Here is the code snippet

```
const amounts = await router(account).getAmountsOut(amountIn, [tokenContract,BNB_CONTRACT]);

if (parseInt(slippage) !== 0) {
    amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].mul(`${slippage}`).div(100));
  } else {
    amountOutMin = amounts[1];
  }
  const approve = await sellTokenContract.approve(PAN_ROUTER_ADDRESS, amountIn);
  const receipt_approve = await approve.wait();
  if (receipt_approve && receipt_approve.blockNumber && receipt_approve.status === 1) { 
    console.log(`Approved https://bscscan.com/tx/${receipt_approve.transactionHash}`);
    console.log("Swapping the tokens.............");
    const swap_txn = await contract.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
      amountIn ,amountOutMin, 
      [tokenContract, BNB_CONTRACT],
      accountAddress,
      (Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10),
      {
        'gasLimit': gasLimit,
        'gasPrice': gasPrice,
      }
    );
    const receipt = await swap_txn.wait();
```

The approve mtx is mined successfully, I can see it in explorer as well https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1fe119ea779b5b329c8ecb769c436a1dc62f1abc612772e275a89131c066cf2b

But the swap fails, this is the tx https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe71ce7dee154ba24442859a83788df9e8b988c7666399e2e6634a4265314f2c3

Thanks

Comment: Looking at the transaction in tenderly dashboard the `transferFrom` in the Safuu token runs out of gas, so you could try with more gas.

Comment: thank you..but I do not think it is gas related, since there was enough gas in the tx...

Comment: From the stack trace in the dashboard it appears safuu token is rebalancing the swap pair and run out of gas there.